Avoid from the Mis-Tokenizing text
I just wondering, why does RoBERTaTokenizer give mis-tokenizing? Here it's the example

I just want to avoid this mis-tokenizing, so I can build my own custom data named entity recognition. Maybe is there any kind of enlightenment?
I just want to know the alternative ways to avoid mis-tokenizing such as giving some conditional based on its vocab.txt or any else.

The tokenizer does exactly what I would expect. Please tell us what you expect.

@cronoik Example if i have the sentences such as "commander give your number", it will be ['comm', 'ander', 'Ġgive', 'Ġyour', 'Ġnumber']. But, my entity label is [start_index , end_index, "Commander"]. It should be Commander, not "comm" and "ander"

@cronoik I like to consider tokenizing the label Commander in [start_index , end_index, "Commander"], but it will be same situation

Your approach will badly hurt the performance because the model you are using has never "seen" a Commander token and you will also lose the flexibility to classify unknown words. The best performance will be achieved by training to classify comm (depending on your data also ander) and for inference you will perform some postprecessing to map the tokens back to the word.

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.
